# Any value in "averages",if it falls in"Interval(1.96)",append corresponding "Closest City" in a list for that interval

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want [image]to iterate over values from column "Interval(1.96)". Any value in "averages",if it falls in the interval,append the corresponding "Closest City" value in a list for that interval.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please come up with a [MCVE] and describe your efforts and then your error/exceptions from your code?